# Ref a picture within a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I would like to know if we can reference a (tikz)picture within a node from another picture. In this way, I could create a PDF with multiple pictures which give details of each node from my first picture. 
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. However, we need some more details. Do you want to reference the figure number of the other tikzpicture or something else? In the first case simply but the picture into a `figure` environment and use `\caption{<text>}\label{<label>}` after it, but before the `\end{figure}`. Then you can reference it using `\ref{<label>}` from anywhere, including a node from another picture. This need two compiler run to get you stable output, BTW.

Comment: Also please check the PGF/TikZ manual for `[remember picture,overlay]` options. Maybe your question is also related to that sort of referencing. As Martin mentioned if you can give a little more detail, we can have a better look.

Comment: Thanks Martin, it's what I wanted to know. A question however, I used :
`\node[state] (A_1) [right of=A_0] {$A_1$ \ref{MyLabel}};`
But a "1" appears and I wonder if we can apply the link on the node

Answer (score 3):

See section **16.13 Referencing Nodes Outside the Current Pictures**
in the Ti*k*Z/PGF-manual. It shows a nice example on how to do this.

I cite the relevant example below.

---

Inside the current text we place two pictures, containing nodes named n1 and n2, using

```
\tikz[remember picture] \node[circle,fill=red!50] (n1) {};
```

which yields (1), and

```
\tikz[remember picture] \node[fill=blue!50] (n2) {};
```

yielding the node (2). To connect these nodes, we create another picture using the overlay option and also the remember picture option.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->,very thick] (n1) -- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

In the manual you will see a line drawn from (1) to (2). I think that shows the possibilities and features of `[remember picture,overlay]` pretty well.

Comment: It's not what I was looking for but it's really interesting and good to know, thanks!